# Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!

Tags: solidity

I'm new to solidity

I'm trying to create an `ERC20` token.

I get this error when I try to deploy it

```
 "CorepassToken" -- Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!.
```

Here is what I wrote in the contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface IERC20 {

    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}


contract CorepassToken is IERC20 {

    string public constant name = "MyToken";
    string public constant symbol = "CPT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;


    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);


    mapping(address => uint256) balances;

    mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

    uint256 totalSupply_;

    using SafeMath for uint256;


   constructor(uint256 total) public {
    totalSupply_ = total;
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
    }

    function totalSupply() public override view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public override view returns (uint256) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function transfer(address receiver, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[msg.sender]);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[receiver] = balances[receiver].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address delegate, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][delegate] = numTokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, delegate, numTokens);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address owner, address delegate) public override view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[owner][delegate];
    }

    function transferFrom(address owner, address buyer, uint256 numTokens) public override returns (bool) {
        require(numTokens <= balances[owner]);
        require(numTokens <= allowed[owner][msg.sender]);

        balances[owner] = balances[owner].sub(numTokens);
        allowed[owner][msg.sender] = allowed[owner][msg.sender].sub(numTokens);
        balances[buyer] = balances[buyer].add(numTokens);
        emit Transfer(owner, buyer, numTokens);
        return true;
    }
}

library SafeMath {
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      assert(b <= a);
      return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
      uint256 c = a + b;
      assert(c >= a);
      return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening, because most likely in the code where you're deploying the contract you're not passing the constructor parameter which you contract is expecting ( `uint256 total` ).

I assume you're using truffle to deploy this contract so your code should be looking like this:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(CorepassToken, <THE_NUMBER_OF_TOTAL_SUPPLY>);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question with certainty you would have to share the code that triggers your token deployment.

Judging from the error message you missed to pass in the constructor argument. Your token has the following constructor `constructor(uint256 total)`, therefore you need to provide a valid `uint256` for the `total` parameter when deploying your contract.